# Disable button in angularjs to ensure process termination without double request

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem where I need to disable my process button
to avoid several requests are sent to the server which in my case means
Duplicate records in stock. So I made the code below
but it is not working the button is not disabled you can
help me in this case thanks.

my html:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <button  type="submit" 
             id="continue" 


             ng-disable="isDisabled" 
             ng-model="isDisabled" 


             ng-click="controller.save()" 
             class="btn btn-primary-default" 
             uib-tooltip="{{'buttons.save'| translate}}" 
             name="continue" 
             ng-focus= "controller.checkList()">
            
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" 
                    aria-hidden="true">
                </span> 
                <span>
                    {{'buttons.save'| translate}}
                </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

my angularjs:

```
$scope.isDisabled = false;
this.myfunction = function() {
    ... my code

$scope.isDisabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you share more javascript code to better understand the problem.
The name of the directive is 'ng-disabled'.
You surely need to pass the variable to true when you start the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button  type="submit" 
         id="continue" 

         ̶n̶g̶-̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶=̶"̶i̶s̶D̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶"̶
         ng-disabled="isDisabled"

         ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶i̶s̶D̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶"̶ ̶

         ng-click="controller.save()" 
         class="btn btn-primary-default" 
         uib-tooltip="{{'buttons.save'| translate}}" 
         name="continue" 
         ng-focus= "controller.checkList()">

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" 
                aria-hidden="true">
            </span> 
            <span>
                {{'buttons.save'| translate}}
            </span>
</button>
```

The name of the directive is `ng-disabled`, ends with a "ed".

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-disabled Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)